# List arguments for ssoadm

Tags: opensso, openam

Can anyone tell me how to separate list arguments in an openam ssoadm call? For example how do i list multiple trusted providers in the create-cot call?

ssoadm -u amadmin -f conf/pwd -e myRealm -t myCOT -trustedproviders *"what goes here"*

I cannot seem to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssoadm -u amadmin -f conf/pwd -e myRealm -t myCOT -trustedproviders "trustedprovider1" "trustedprovider2"
```